# How To Change The Position Of A Class

Tags: javascript

So I have a div, and I want to change the position of it by its class, this is my code.

```
<h1 class="test">Hi!</h1>

<script>
x = document.getElementsByClassName('test')

x[0].style.top = 500;

</script>
```

However the position remains the same, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the default element `position` is `static` and that means any manipulation to the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` **CSS** properties isn't going to be visibly applied.

So, if you wanted to change the `top` properties, you also need to change the element `position` with any of the following value:

`relative`
`absolute`
`fixed`

You can learn more about the **CSS Positions** in [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

So in order for your case to work, the following code as follows:

```
<h1 class="test">Hi!</h1>

<script>
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('test')

  x[0].style.position = 'relative'; // Changed the position property to relative.
  x[0].style.top = '500px'; // Must be wrapped in quotes, and append the measurement unit in the value in this case the 'px'.

</script>
```

You can also learn more about **CSS Measurement Units** in [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_measurement_units.htm)